# Perl: How can I get Emacs to add quotes to full path of a Perl script?

Tags: perl, emacs

Embarassingly simple question. Using CPerl mode in Emacs 23.4.1 on Windows 7 64, when I use `C-c c` to run the script Emacs doesn't wrap the path in quotes, so any directories with spaces cause Perl to be unable to find the file.
`"C:/Perl64/bin\perl.exe -w g:/foo/bar/first second/myscript.pl"`
generates this error message:
`"Can't open perl script "g:/foo/bar/first": No such file or directory"`

Question: how do I make Emacs use quotes when passing the file name to Perl itself?

Edit: for some reason I can't comment (perhaps a browser issue) so I am editing the original post in response to the comment from @legoscia: "C-c c runs the command mode-compile". In the Perl menu it is marked as "Run".

Comment: `C-c c` seems to be a non-standard binding. What do you get if you type `C-h c C-c c`?

Comment: `mode-compile.el` isn't standard. Are you using http://perso.tls.cena.fr/boubaker/distrib/mode-compile.el or something else?

Comment: @phils I'm not intentionally using `mode-compile.el` - I have no recollection of trying to install it nor would there be need for me to do so directly as the only languages I use are interpreted (R, Perl). Perhaps it is something that was installed with ESS...? When a Perl script is in the buffer, the major mode is CPerl and the minor mode is Abbrev. There's nothing else obviously different.

Comment: Use `M-x find-library RET mode-compile RET` to open the code for that library. The commentary at the top will probably ascertain where it came from (and the location of that file will probably tell you if it came with ESS, assuming it keeps its files under a common directory?)

Comment: Bingo, M. Boubaker's mode-compile.el v2.29.1. So... What would you recommend I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only have mode-compile.el v2.29 available, but in that version the issue is exactly as you describe, the arguments to the compile command are not escaped properly, and there's no option to enable it.

It's a bit of hack but you should be able to redefine the relevant function with correct escaping for the filename with this in your `.emacs` file:

```el
(eval-after-load 'mode-compile
  '(progn
    (defun mc--shell-compile (shell dbgflags &optional errors-regexp-alist)
      ;; Run SHELL with debug flags DBGFLAGS on current-buffer
      (let* ((shcmd   (or (mc--which shell)
                          (error "Compilation abort: command %s not found" shell)))
             (shfile  (or mc--remote-pathname (buffer-file-name)
                          (error "Compilation abort: Buffer %s has no filename"
                                 (buffer-name))))
             (run-cmd (concat shcmd " " dbgflags " " (shell-quote-argument shfile) " "
                              (setq mc--shell-args
                                    (read-string (if mode-compile-expert-p
                                                     "Argv: "
                                                   (format "Arguments to %s %s script: "
                                                           shfile shell))
                                                 mc--shell-args)))))
        ;; Modify compilation-error-regexp-alist if needed
        (if errors-regexp-alist
            (progn
              ;; Set compilation-error-regexp-alist from compile
              (or (listp errors-regexp-alist)
                  (error "Compilation abort: In mc--shell-compile errors-regexp-alist not a list."))
              ;; Add new regexp alist to compilation-error-regexp-alist
              (mapcar '(lambda(x)
                         (if (mc--member x compilation-error-regexp-alist) nil
                           (setq compilation-error-regexp-alist
                                 (append (list x)
                                         compilation-error-regexp-alist))))
                      errors-regexp-alist)))
        ;; Run compile with run-cmd
        (mc--compile run-cmd)))))
```

The line I changed was changing

```el
(run-cmd (concat shcmd " " dbgflags " " shfile " "
```

to

```el
(run-cmd (concat shcmd " " dbgflags " " (shell-quote-argument shfile) " "
```

A more complete fix would be to also escape the `dbgflags` (wherever they're set, just escaping the entire variable won't be right) and `mc--shell-args` when they're set too.

Comment: +1, but I would suggest writing to the author and getting this fixed at the source. p.s. If you prefix your elisp code with `<!-- language: lang-el -->` Stack Overflow will get the syntax highlighting correct.

Comment: Useful tip, thanks, and indeed, sending a patch upstream is always wise.